# How does the GCM or cloud server know if it's the same tablet that's trying to register again?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How does the GCM or cloud server know if it's the same tablet that's trying to register again? i mean, you only send the sender id, the same sender id for the same app right? so how does the server know if it's a different device, does the GCMRegistrar also implicitly send a certain device ID together with the sender ID and the package name?

I'm puzzled how it saves the registration. What if I uninstall the app on my tablet, will it also remove the registration ID in the gcm server? What if I reinstall the app after uninstalling, will it provide the same registration ID or create a new one? how will it know that it's the same device?

Also I don't know that's the use of unregistering from GCM. why would I do that unless my app is being uninstalled?

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838654/handling-registration-id-changes-in-google-cloud-messaging-on-android

Comment: a lot of answers are there ,see this and  also the links on the right bottom of this linked page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16278977/gcm-how-to-unregister-a-device-with-gcm-and-3rd-party-server

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answers! :) so to clarify, does this mean that if the app is being uninstalled, GCMRegistrar will send notification to the server to delete the registrationID? And that when the app is uninstalled/reinstalled on the same device, a new registrationID will be given?

Comment: hi sir I'm currently having problems with my WMS request opacity, please help at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27936381/how-do-i-set-the-opacity-of-a-wms-requested-layer-in-android-google-maps-api. Thank you :)